# React TS Is there a better way to render a list of elements and passing down useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[Code Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-mccarthy-x34u3j?file=/src/App.tsx)

What I'm trying to do is render a list with a few elements and have a counter
on the root element which i want to update every time one of the button is clicked
But I'm not sure this is the best way, i'm coming from Blazor and i had some difficulties
on rendering N elements, in c# we would do a for loop directly on the html.
I get back the button text just to try that out i know i have the button text on the line before in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [improved way](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-mestorf-8dlg9n?file=/src/App.tsx) you may need.

Comment: wow thanks a lot, much more cleaner!!

Comment: why the undefined in useState<number | undefined>() ?

Comment: It's because there is no any clicked button in start, so initial value would be undefined.